# Properties don't take effect until second execution

Tags: multithreading, variables, properties

I'm running scripts that require a different thread for each user account I pull from a database. So the script starts by running a JDBC processor to get all the accounts and store them (using the "Variable Names" field) in "accounts". Then I run a BeanShell PreProcessor to convert the variable "accounts_#" to a property:

```
props.put("p_accounts_#",vars.get("accounts_#"));
```

Then, I have a thread group start. Under "Number of Threads (users)", I have

```
${__P(p_accounts_#)}
```

The **FIRST** time I run this script (after launching jMeter), I only get a SINGLE thread. Every subsequent time I run it, it runs for all accounts.

It seems like for some reason, the property is not being saved until the end of the first execution. This is a very big problem as when jMeter is launched without the UI, it only does a single thread every time.

Am I setting the property incorrectly? I also tried it with a Beanshell Assertion with the same result.

Just as a test, I created a new test with the bare minimum I needed to reproduce this. Here's the script (images): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY6i2.jpg

It's a Beanshell PreProcessor with "props.put("accounts","12");"
Then a Thread group using "${__P(accounts)}" as the Number of Threads
Then inside that thread group is a Debug Sampler outputting the JMeter properties.
At the end is a View Results Tree.

When I run it the first time, there's only one output: "Thread 1 Running".
When I run it again, there's 12 outputs, "Tread 1 Running", "Thread 2 running", etc.

I can see that for both Debug Samplers (for the first run and second run), the "Accounts" property is set to 12. But the Thread Group needed to execute TWICE before it would work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by adding another ThreadGroup called a 'setUp ThreadGroup' to contain the setup portion.  If you put all of your staging steps into this type of threadgroup, it will run prior to any other threadgroups.  You can then have your preprocessor, or move the logic to a beanshell sampler if you'd like, and set the property from there.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I added a new thread group, set the option to "Run Thread Groups consecutively" in the test plan and used a Beanshell Sampler to set up the property. It seems the Beanshell preprocessor was not doing anything but the sampler works fine. Thanks!